# Does rails support variations on has_and_belongs_to_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, join

Essentially we have two models and a Join table

```
class Guests < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :guests
end

class CreateJoinTableGuestsEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :guests, :events do |t|
      t.index [:guest_id, :event_id]
      t.index [:event_id, :guest_id]
    end
  end
end
```

What I really mean to have is:

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :event
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guests
end
```

Is it possible for it to use the join table?

Answer (score 1):

if you really want has_one and belongs_to you should not use a join table. It is enough to add the `guest_id` to the event.

Answer (score 0):

Build a [one_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) association. here is how it will look.

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :guests
end
```

you can get guests of an event by `event.guests` and to get the event where a user is a gust will be `guest.event`